# Vee-Validate date type input validation (Bootstrap-vue)

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue, vee-validate

I'm trying to use vee-validate to check if the user is typing a valid date in a bootstrap-vue date input. Followed the vee-validate docs, but seems not to have the expected behaviour

Not working with valid dates nor invalid dates like 31/06/2019 (dd/MM/yyyy)

Here is a codepen example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wVewvK

```
<b-form-input v-model="selectedDate"
                  placeholder="Enter date"
                  v-validate="'date_format:dd/MM/yyyy'"
                  name="sdate"
                  type="date">
    </b-form-input>
```

Docs:

https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/validation/#veevalidate

https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#date-format

Answer (score 0):

Native browser `date` inputs expect a date (as a string) in a certain format, which is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

You will need to use a `text` type input if you want to use a date that is formatted any differently from what the browser expects.

```html
<b-form-input
  v-model="selectedDate"
  placeholder="Enter date"
  v-validate="'date_format:dd/MM/yyyy'"
  name="sdate"
  type="text">
</b-form-input>
```

Comment: Actually I don't need any specific format, I just need the user to type a valid date. Like using his keyboard, he can type 31/06/2019. This must throw an error. I don't want to use text type, coz I want the date picker to be available as well. Changing the format to YYYY/MM/DD doesn't help in my codepen example.

Comment: I made a mistake in my original answer... the format a native date input expects is `YYYY-MM-DD`. I have update the answer.

Comment: Vee-Validate also inspects the input type, and deduces the correct format the date should be in, which is conflicting with the format you are specifying. Note that not all browsers support native date inputs (most modern browsers will, but IE 11 doesn't). In those cases the browser will render the equivalent of a text input which would allow the user to type in any invalid format.

Answer (score 0):

OK.. just found that in case of `input type="date"` you don't need to do any format validation. Just the `required` option of vee-validate will do the job and won't accept any invalid dates

I have updated the codepen:

```
      <b-form-input :state="!errors.has('sdate')"
                    v-model="selectedDate"
                    placeholder="Enter sdate"
                    v-validate="'required'"
                    name="sdate"
                    type="date">
      </b-form-input>
```